# Weird java recursion nullpointerexception on a method

Tags: java, recursion

Hi I'm writing a checkers engine and defining a canEat(Point1,Point2) method for player class which returns true or false based on if player can eat eat the piece at the specified points by checking if the pieces and landing path is on board, if the two pieces belong to the same player or not and also considering the king/super status of piece.

Anyways it works pretty pleasantly without recursion, but without recursion method must get points of the pieces instead of the landing piece which is okay if I manage the recursion. But I want the method to also consider if it gets the landing point instead of piece location. When I run the code it fixes the location and calls itself again there is no problem with that but. I get  NullPointerException on 
caneat = Checker2.isAlive() ? true : false; because Checker2 is null. My pointToChecker method returns null on this guy so Checker2 is null. What is causing this I'm new to recursion, even OOP to be honest and
Here is my code and console error log

```
public boolean canEat(Point Piece, Point target)
{
    //INITIALIZING
    //POINT1 & CHECKER1-> piece which eats
    //POINT2 & CHECKER2-> piece to eat
    //POINT3 & CHECKER3-> landing path


    if (samePoint(Piece, target))
        return false;

    boolean caneat = true;      
    boolean king1 = false;
    Point Point1,Point2,Point3;
    Checker Checker1,Checker2,Checker3;
    int ownerID, victimID,axis;
    axis = getDirection(Piece, target);

    //CHECK IF PLAYER POINTED THE SQUARE AHEAD TARGET PIECE OR THE PIECE TO EAT
    int distance = getStep(Piece, target);
    if(distance == 2)
    {
        boolean resolution;
        System.err.println("Recoordinated target");
        Point fixed = getBackwards(target, axis);
        System.err.println("Fixed is: " + Piece + "  " + fixed);
        resolution = canEat(Piece, fixed);
        return resolution;
    }


    Point1 = Piece;
    Point2 = target;
    Point3 = findMovePosition(target, axis);

    if(!inBoard(Point1) || !inBoard(Point2) || !inBoard(Point3))
    {   
        System.err.println("Error: Invalid Move --> Thinking outside the box");
        return false;
    }


    Checker1 = PointToPiece(Point1);
    Checker2 = PointToPiece(Point2);
    Checker3 = PointToPiece(Point3);

    //CHECK IF PIECES ARE ALIVE
    caneat = Checker1.isAlive() ? true : false;
    caneat = Checker2.isAlive() ? true : false;

    if(!Checker2.isAlive())
    {
        return false;
    }
        //THERE SHOULD BE TARGET AND VICTIM PIECES AND AN EMPTY LANDING POINT
    if(!isOccupied(Piece))
        {           
        System.err.println("#OccupyChecker invalid piece to move");
        return false;
        }
        if(!isOccupiedbyEnemy(target))
        {
        System.err.println("#OccupyChecker invalid piece to eat");
        return false;
        }
        if(!(Checker3 == null))
        {
        System.err.println("#OccupyChecker landing piece error");
        return false;
        }
    ownerID = Checker1.getOwner().getID();
    victimID = Checker2.getOwner().getID();

    if(ownerID == victimID)
    {
        System.err.println("owner ID: " + ownerID + " victimID: " + victimID);
        System.err.println("#OCCUPY identity");
        return false;
    }


    if(ownerID == 1 && king1)
    {
        if(axis == 3 || axis == 4)
            System.err.println("#OccupyPoint wrong axis");
            caneat = false;
    }
    if(ownerID == 2 && king1)
    {
        if(axis == 1 || axis == 2)
            System.err.println("#OccupyPoint wrong axis");
            caneat = false;
    }

    return caneat;

}


Checker PointToPiece(Point piece)
{
    Checker[] allPieces = allPieces();
    Checker found = null;
    for(Checker k : allPieces)
    {
        if(samePoint(k.getPosition(), piece))
            found = k;
    }
    return found;


}
```

Comment: `PointToPiece` is the function that suppose to fill those variables, thus publishing it will be pretty handy.. Also, an full exception output will be useful.

Comment: `Checker2` is only set by the call to `pointToPiece(Point2)`, so that must be what's failing. You haven't shown us that function, but if you figure out what could possibly cause it to return null... (By the way, the convention is that variable names should start with a lowercase letter; only types should start with uppercase.)

Comment: Apologies i did not realize it would be required i publish it right away

Comment: i just added that method. I implemented most of the methods in single class named Player. I thought it would be wrong to put all code here and give unnecessary exhaustion to people who read it. Apologies newbie around here

Comment: @photonist, I would suggest you to debug `PointToPiece` and have a look why doesn't it enter to `found = k` because you expect it to..

Comment: either `samePoint` is never true in some case or `allPieces` is an empty collection

Comment: i hold all the checker pieces of the player in an array of Checker object. PointtoPiece scans that array and returns the Checker which has the coordinate the method takes as the input. I am not familiar with debugging this is my first serious project on programming unfortunately. I will try debugging right now though

Comment: the problem is definately with the allPieces method it returns null Checker Object to the pointToPiece method but couldn't figure out why so far

Comment: AHH FOUND IT! it was nothing but zoning out due to too much focusing on it. I was testing this method with a tester method that contains some points and player objects. I was manually changing position of an enemy piece to some coordinate to test the canEat method. i was actually changing the piece position instead of coordinate information which i feed the canEat method with. And now i also discovered a new potential problem to fix with this new cool recursive method!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't know how to upvote comments though but thank you